# Sony SmartWatch - How to pass data to control extension?

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

If I would like to pass some data (via bundle or something else) to my control extension with `CONTROL_START_REQUEST_INTENT` action, what I can do?

I don't see any Intent or Bundle object being passed to the constructor of ControlExtension class.

Comment: I recommend [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971674/how-should-i-do-to-start-smartwatch-extension-from-the-program-code) and the answer to be seen.

Comment: @tarosay "this question" doesn't answer my question. A ControlExtension can be invoked by user tap the app icon on watch or send an CONTROL_START_REQUEST_INTENT action. If is invoked by the action intent, I would like the ControlExtension to perform some different behavior than manually invoked by user. That's why I want to pass data to ControlExtension with CONTROL_START_REQUEST_INTENT intent.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to know if the ControlExtension was started by the user from the watch, or if you requested a start yourself via the START_REQUEST intent. The resulting start sent from the host application does not provide such information.

You could solve it by setting a flag when you send the START_REQUEST intent, and then you will know (to a certain extent, not 100% of course) that the extension was started via a request and not by the user. It is a work around, but as I said, not waterproof.

Can you give me an example of what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: This workaround is not a good solution. I have done this in my "2x Battery" app with a dirty solution. 
Here is an example, when the phone's battery is low, 2x will use CONTROL_START_REQUEST_INTENT to show a control extension on watch and vibrate. If user tap the screen when vibrating, 2x won't insert an event; otherwise an event will be added at onPause() so user can be notified later. The "auto add event" code should not be enabled if the control extension is invoked by user manually.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the preferences for this?

Prior to using the START_REQUEST, put a value in the preferences that the extension is started on a request, and from the extension code just check for the existence of that value.

However, IMO you should rethink your app logic.