# SmartWatch Call Handling (start an extension from another extension)

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

Is there a way that I start Sony's "Call handling" extension, from my own extension which triggers the call?

To make myself clear, I just want to:

1) Programatically close (shut down) my extension and 
2) Programatically open the "Call handling" extension

That's exactly what the Phonebook extension does - when it initiates a call, the "Call handling" extension is started. My extension also initiates a call, I just don't know how to transfer the control to the "Call handling".

So, it's possible, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that's possible, despite the answer of Jerker (=Sony's support). Maybe I didn't know how to properly ask. Nevermind, here's the solution:

1) to close my extension:

```
sendToHostApp(new Intent(Control.Intents.CONTROL_STOP_REQUEST_INTENT));
```

2) to launch a different extension - follow the instructions given here: [How should I do to start SmartWatch Extension from the program code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971674/how-should-i-do-to-start-smartwatch-extension-from-the-program-code)

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for the "Call handling" extension, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think I need an API, I just want to: 1) close my extension programatically and then 2) launch the call handling extension, also programatically. 
Isn't that possible?

Comment: Ok, that is definitely possible, since that's what the Phonebook extension does when it starts a call, it transfers the control to the Call handling extension. I want to do the same. How?

Comment: The Sony extensions does have access to the Call Handling extension, that is correct, but it is currently not possible for third party extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is "a bit" disappointing. What's the point of having a smart phone extension which actually cannot use the phone functionality? 

Even more, all I want is only to end my extension and to start another one, why is that so complicated?