# How to open the notification view from a smartwatch widget?

Tags: sony-smartwatch

I would like to make my custom widget which I want to use the short taps on some area of my custom widget to navigate to my notification list and short taps on another area to navigate to my control. Is it possible ?

I found the sample code to open the control from a widget in this answer: [How should I do to start SmartWatch Extension from the program code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971674)!

But I didn't found the sample code to open the notification list from a widget.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question.

If you are asking if it's possible to open the notification drawer on your phone from a widget on the SmartWatch the answer is no, the notification drawer cannot be opened using any public APIs in the Android SDK.

If you are talking about opening a notification list on the watch itself, using the SmartExtension SDK Notification API then yes you can but you need to create the UI yourself and retrieve the notifications via the Content Provider.  There is an example of a notification extension in the Sony Add-on SDK in the sample code section.